# Stringing together a sentence from data that includes dates

Tags: excel, date, format, equation, sentence

I have a question regarding this topic;

I'm also looking to put together a string of data into a sentence using excel, and the issue I'm running into involves dates.

="ISP Annual was completed on "&('(1) Checklists 1'!E12)& " as an "&'(1) Checklists 1'!H12&" investigation." is my equation, where the'(1) Checklists 1'!E12 would normally resource a date into the sentence. Resourcing it alone creates a date, but when I try the above equation, it converts it into a serial number "43151." I've tried DATEVALUE to remedy it, but it breaks the equation. Is there an easier way to do this?

Resource question that I have reviewed in an attempt to understand an answer:
[Make sentence from data in cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907671/make-sentence-from-data-in-cells-in-excel/54025327#54025327)

Comment: Use the `TEXT` function to format the date when concatenating.

Comment: Thank you Big Ben; it worked like a charm.